# unable to execute pig script for Hue-2.5.0

Tags: apache-pig, hue

I have installed Hue-2.5.0 in pseudo mode and also i am able to view the UI.

Beeswax(hive UI), sqoop, oozie editor everything are working efficiently but i dont know why my pig scripts are not working, UI is non resrponsiv & it is not showing any errors or exceptions.

i have checked logs also and found no issue

what could be the issue???

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `http://hue_host:8888/logs`, or right click and 'inspect element' and look for error in the Chrome console. You can also share a screenshot of what happens when you clicked 'submit. Feel free to comment on the [hue-user](http://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/group/hue-user) list too.

Comment: no logs available in logs  and  due to inefficiency of reputation am not able to share screen shot.